# Xorg -configure doesn't work with nouveau drivers

Tags: xorg, kernel-modules, nvidia, drivers

I'm having problems setting up X.org on Gentoo.

At the moment I have kernel 2.6.37-gentoo-r4 installed and have built X against this kernel. I have nouveau  drivers installed and they seem to be working correctly, from what I can see in terminal. I have nVIdia GeForce 9500M GS and it should be supported by the driver since it uses the NV84 (G84) core.

When I try to startx, this is what I get:

```
ZVEZDA ~ # startx
hostname: Unknown host
xauth:  file /root/.serverauth.4316 does not exist


X.Org X Server 1.9.4
Release Date: 2011-02-04
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.37-gentoo-r4 x86_64 Gentoo
Current Operating System: Linux ZVEZDA 2.6.37-gentoo-r4 #2 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 11 14:00:26 CEST 2011 x86_64
Kernel command line: root=/dev/sda3 nouveau.modeset=1
Build Date: 11 April 2011  02:02:40PM

Current version of pixman: 0.20.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Apr 11 14:13:09 2011
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
(EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
resize called 1920 1200
(EE) Logitech USB Receiver: failed to initialize for relative axes.
(EE) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad no synaptics event device found
(EE) Query no Synaptics: 6003C8
(EE) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad Unable to query/initialize Synaptics hardware.
(EE) PreInit failed for input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
which: no keychain in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.5.2)
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc: line 61: xterm: command not found
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc: line 63: exec: xterm: not found
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc: line 59: twm: command not found
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down
```

When I try to configure Xorg, I get:

```
ZVEZDA Xorg # Xorg -configure

X.Org X Server 1.9.4
Release Date: 2011-02-04
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.36-gentoo-r5 x86_64 Gentoo
Current Operating System: Linux ZVEZDA 2.6.37-gentoo-r4 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 11 13:37:39 CEST 2011 x86_64
Kernel command line: root=/dev/sda3 nouveau.modeset=1
Build Date: 18 March 2011  09:54:54PM

Current version of pixman: 0.20.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Apr 11 14:04:54 2011
List of video drivers:
        nouveau
(++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) [drm] No DRICreatePCIBusID symbol
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
```

The log says:

```
[    47.459] 
X.Org X Server 1.9.4
Release Date: 2011-02-04
[    47.461] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    47.461] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.37-gentoo-r4 x86_64 Gentoo
[    47.462] Current Operating System: Linux ZVEZDA 2.6.37-gentoo-r4 #2 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 11 14:00:26 CEST 2011 x86_64
[    47.463] Kernel command line: root=/dev/sda3 nouveau.modeset=1
[    47.464] Build Date: 11 April 2011  02:02:40PM
[    47.465]  
[    47.465] Current version of pixman: 0.20.2
[    47.466]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    47.468] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    47.470] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Apr 11 15:58:36 2011
[    47.471] (II) Loader magic: 0x7d5140
[    47.471] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    47.471]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    47.471]    X.Org Video Driver: 8.0
[    47.471]    X.Org XInput driver : 11.0
[    47.471]    X.Org Server Extension : 4.0
[    47.472] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0405:1025:011e rev 161, Mem @ 0xd2000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00005000/128
[    47.473] List of video drivers:
[    47.473]    nouveau
[    47.474] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    47.474] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    47.474] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    47.474]    compiled for 1.9.4, module version = 0.0.16
[    47.474]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    47.474]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    47.475] (II) NOUVEAU driver 
[    47.475] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    47.475]    RIVA TNT    (NV04)
[    47.475]    RIVA TNT2   (NV05)
[    47.475]    GeForce 256 (NV10)
[    47.475]    GeForce 2   (NV11, NV15)
[    47.475]    GeForce 4MX (NV17, NV18)
[    47.475]    GeForce 3   (NV20)
[    47.475]    GeForce 4Ti (NV25, NV28)
[    47.475]    GeForce FX  (NV3x)
[    47.475]    GeForce 6   (NV4x)
[    47.475]    GeForce 7   (G7x)
[    47.475]    GeForce 8   (G8x)
[    47.491] (++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
[    47.491] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    47.492] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
[    47.492] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    47.492] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    47.492] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
[    47.492] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    47.492] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    47.492] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    47.493] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    47.493] (**) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/misc/,
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/OTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/Type1/,
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi/,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi/,
    /usr/share/fonts/misc/,
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/OTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/Type1/,
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi/,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi/
[    47.493] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
[    47.493] (WW) AllowEmptyInput is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    47.493] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    47.493] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    47.493] (EE) [drm] No DRICreatePCIBusID symbol
[    47.493] Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
```

There are some interesting lines in those files, for example this:

```
    [    47.475] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
    [    47.475]    RIVA TNT    (NV04)
    [    47.475]    RIVA TNT2   (NV05)
    [    47.475]    GeForce 256 (NV10)
    [    47.475]    GeForce 2   (NV11, NV15)
    [    47.475]    GeForce 4MX (NV17, NV18)
    [    47.475]    GeForce 3   (NV20)
    [    47.475]    GeForce 4Ti (NV25, NV28)
    [    47.475]    GeForce FX  (NV3x)
    [    47.475]    GeForce 6   (NV4x)
    [    47.475]    GeForce 7   (G7x)
    [    47.475]    GeForce 8   (G8x)
```

and

```
    [    47.493] (EE) [drm] No DRICreatePCIBusID symbol
    [    47.493] Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
      Configuration failed.
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: Hard To Say, could you post the content of your xorg.conf file(s)?  
It appears you are running as the 'root' user, is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Chris2048 I'm running as root right now because I'm still setting up the system. There is no other special reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also get the `No DRICreatePCIBusID symbol` error when I try to run `X -configure` on my system. Thankfully, I didn't really need to run it in order to make X run. These are the files inside my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`:

- 10-evdev.conf
- 10-monitor.conf
- 10-quirks.conf
- 20-nouveau.conf

`10-evdev.conf` and `10-quirks.conf` came with the `xorg-server` package.
`10-monitor.conf` contains the config from the ArchWiki's [Xorg page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Monitor_settings), without the `Device` section,  and `20-nouveau.conf` from the [Nouveau page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nouveau#Configuration).

*10-monitor.conf:*

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier     "VGA-1"
        Option "PreferredMode" "1280x1024"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier     "TV-1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier     "Screen0"
        Device         "NVIDIA Card"
        DefaultDepth    24

        SubSection     "Display"
                Depth       24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

*20-nouveau.conf:*

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier    "NVIDIA Card"
    Driver        "nouveau"
EndSection
```

---

The following errors tells us that you haven't installed xterm and twm.

```
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc: line 61: xterm: command not found
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc: line 63: exec: xterm: not found
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc: line 59: twm: command not found
```

You might want to `emerge` them or create a `~/.xinitrc` file to override the system-wide xinitrc file.

You might want to post the log for when you are trying to run X normally (i.e. startx). The one you posted is the log after trying to run `Xorg -configure`.

Comment: Is there a list of commonly needed programs I should install? I would usually just emerge x11-base/xorg-x11 and get xterm and friends.

Comment: You might want to install a Desktop Environment like KDE, GNOME, or Xfce. Other common X11 programs are a browser (e.g. Chrom[e|ium], Firefox) The [Gentoo Documentation Resources](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/list.xml?desc=1) and the [Gentoo Wiki](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Main_Page) are good resources.

Comment: I already have GNOME installed, but can't start it until I can get Xorg to work.  Those two links saved me countless times over the years, but they are sometimes a bit out of date (and they didn't mention that xterm has to be installed by hand now).

Comment: Try creating `~/.xinitrc` containing `exec ck-launch-session gnome-session`, then run `startx`.

Comment: Starting GNOME directly somehow solved the problem.